# Why would a statement execute in Toad but not in my code?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, devart, dotconnect

Here is my code:

```
private void UpdatePlatypus(String APetPlatypus) 
{
    oracleConnectionMainForm.Open();
    OracleCommand ocmd = new OracleCommand();
    ocmd.Connection = oracleConnectionMainForm;
    try 
    {
        ocmd.CommandText = @"<Update SQL statement that contains one parameter, like so: "WHERE DUCKBILLEDPLATYPUS = :PLATYPUS">)";
        ocmd.Parameters.Add("PLATYPUS", APetPlatypus);
        ocmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("UpdatePlatypus failed with message {0}", e.Message));
    } 
    finally 
    {
        oracleConnectionMainForm.Close();
    }
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("UpdatePlatypus to {0} succeeded", APetPlatypus));
}
```

In Toad, this SQL works fine -- I simply replace ":PLATYPUS" with the value "Phineas" in the Toad SQL editor, and the records are, indeed, updated, as the "27 records affected" message and a subsequent SQL Select that returns the updated records shows.

But in my C# app, it hangs on the call to ExecuteNonQuery()...I never see any of the messages - neither that the Update failed, nor that it succeeded - it simply hangs there, floating about in space like a smurf ball on the moon.

### UPDATE

I copied some old Update code for dotConnect for Oracle that worked, but it still does the same thing (hangs on the call to ExecuteNonQuery()

```
private void UpdatePlatypus(String APetPlatypus) {

    OracleCommand ocmd;

    oracleConnectionMainForm.Open();
    String update = @"<same update sql as above>";
    ocmd = new OracleCommand(update, oracleConnectionMainForm);
    ocmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    try {
        OracleParameter p_DuckbilledPlatypus =
        new OracleParameter("DIVISION", OracleDbType.NVarChar, ParameterDirection.Input);
        p_DuckbilledPlatypus.Value = APetPlatypus;
        ocmd.Parameters.Add(p_DuckbilledPlatypus);
        using (var transaction = oracleConnectionMainForm.BeginTransaction()) {
            try {
                ocmd.Transaction = transaction;
                ocmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                transaction.Commit();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("UpdatePlatypus failed with message {0}", e.Message));
    } finally {
        oracleConnectionMainForm.Close();
    }
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("UpdatePlatypus to {0} succeeded", APetPlatypus));
}
```

### ANOTHER UPDATE

Is it possible that the SQL statement can be too confusing for whatever it is that parses it, even though it is valid SQL?

Again, this query runs fine in Toad, but it *is* quite complex: it contains TWO nested Select statements, like so:

```
Update <tableName> 
Set <col = value> 
where <col> in 
(select bla from bla where bla = :Platypus) 
and (bla is null or bla)
and bla in (select distinct bla from bla 
where bla = bla and bla is not null)
```

### YET ANOTHER UPDATE

If I simplify the query by replacing the sub-selects with parameters (that are supplied via the results returned from those atmoic SQL select statements) it runs (and almost instantaneously, at that).

So, I guess the nested subselects *were* too much for whatever it is that parses the Update statement...

Comment: @"<Update SQL statement that contains one parameter, like so: "WHERE DUCKBILLEDPLATYPUS =                :PLATYPUS">)"; is this what you are using or you actually replacing it with a query

Comment: A valid query, that works in Toad, is represented by that left angle bracket, bla bla bla, right angle bracket.

Comment: strip it down into a bare bones repro - eg a Table Schema with dummy data and the update statement that works in TOAD that doesn't work in code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you hit "commit" button in TOAD after executing your UPDATE ? It looks that it hangs simply becacuse of the lock on the updated rows.

BTW: In TOAD, menu Database -> Monitor -> Session Browser, find your "C#" or TOAD oracle sessions and look at the "Locks" tab, there are two sub-tabs "Blocking locks" and "Blocked locks". Is there any entry when your session hangs ?

Comment: I didn't need to hit commit in Toad, because it works in Toad. Visual Studio/C#/devArt dotConnect for Oracle is the problem.

Comment: The session monitoring in Toad sounded promising, but when I tried that I got the dialog:

"Access to the following views required: <a list of views longer than Cyrano de Bergerac's nose, maybe even Pinocchio's>"

Comment: But this morning it worked just fine - same code; so I guess it was some database problem yesterday...

Comment: It worked because you did not update records from toad. Try to update THE SAME records from toad without committing and then run your app and make it to update the same rows as updated by toad. It will hang.

Answer (score 1):

After you `ExecuteNonQuery()` call `ExecuteNonQuery` again with CommandText `COMMIT`. Oracle says it documentation that it commit automatically but actually it's not. It's committing only when you close the connection.